# on click div appear below list item - Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I am not able to see the div when it is outside of the button tag. But I can see it when it's inside. It's basic show - hide functionality, but am not sure the way Ionic works in the sense that it is not visible outside some of the tags.

page.html

```
 <ion-list text-wrap>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of items">
      <button ion-item (click)="onDetails()">
        <ion-note item-left >note left</ion-note>
       <p>content</p>
        <ion-note item-end>note right</ion-note>

 <div *ngIf="details" type="text">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
      </button>

    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
```

component.ts

```
export class ItemPage {

  details: boolean = false;
  index: number;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {


  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
  }


 onDetails(){
   this.details = !this.details;
 }



}
```

I believe this has something to do with on click not receiving a correct index perhaps.

Comment: outside button tag or outside `ion-item-sliding` tag?

Comment: Outside the button tag, it doesn't seem to appear.

Comment: try changing the `div` to `ion-item`... https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/ItemSliding/

Comment: wow...I thought I tried this. Thanks!